# Implementing beq instruction to a simple control unit in logisim

Tags: mips, alu

so i dont know if im stupid but i have tried to research this for offers and i still cant seem to understand how the beq instruction is built? i get that u first extract the 6 lsb to get the opcode and that beq has the opcode 000100 but i dont get what happens after in this picture, why is there a 2 and 6 input to the decoder and why is the ALUControl 010, shouldnt it be sub operator to see if beq is true [logisim beq instruction at bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8CuL.png)

i want to know what happens after the opcode goes into the comparator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like the `BEQ` needs a 6 (subtraction) for `ALUControl`, so gets this 6 from that MUX.  That MUX will select 2 with a mux selector control input 0, and 6 with a mux selector control input 1.  So, when `BEQ`, then a 1 goes to that mux selector control input, as well as to the Branch control signal.

Many other instructions need a 2 and also get it from this MUX, by leaving that mux control selector input at 0 (in that diagram, from "not" `BEQ`).  The `addi`, `addiu`, `add`, `addu`, `lw`, and `sw` instructions (among others) all want 2 (addition) for the ALUControl.

The `sub`, `subu`, `subiu`, `subi` instructions also want 6 (subtract) for the ALUControl, though these are not shown in that limited diagram.  That diagram does not show how the R-Type instructions generate their respective ALUControl values.  It only shows that ALUControl is 6 for `BEQ` and 2 for other than `BEQ`.